# What does "Enable Sales tracker" do?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Checking it changes the dialogue to "Currently monitoring incoming transactions, none found yet."
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does what the text on your screenshot says: it monitors the blockchain for incoming transactions matching the amount you specify. This is intended as a poor man's point of sale system: if you're selling things for monero, you can use this screen with these steps:

- find a customer who wants to buy something and pay with monero
- enter the item's price in the box in your screenshot
- let the customer scan the QR code
- let the customer send monero using that QR code using their wallet
- wait till a transaction is reported on this screen, and check it says the payment is for the full amount
- optionally wait for a confirmation or more
- give the customer the item